# Loosely coupled rules in WF (or another .Net Rules Engine)

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, business-rules

I have been reading up on Windows WF and how to create and execute rules outside of Workflows. However all the examples seem to require a defined class in which to bind the rules to properties.

We have a scenario where an arbitrary list of properties and values is defined at runtime, and we want to execute rules against a KeyValuePair or Dictionary containing these values. If the value is not there, the rule should fail or ignore it.

So for example, say we had rules to recommend movies:

- Rule 1: If Genre = "Thought Provoking" and Rating = "5" then set Movie = "Enemy Mine"
- Rule 2: If Genre = "Scary" and Rating = "5" then set Movie = "Aliens"
- Rule 3: If Genre = "Comedy" and Rating = "2" then set Movie = "Dumb and Dumber"
- Rule 4: If Genre = "Comedy" and Snack = "Caviar" then set Movie = "Big"

If our dictionary contains this list of properties and values:

```
Rating = "5"
Genre = "Thought Provoking" 
Movie = ""
```

This would execute `Rule 1` and the Movie value would get set to "Enemy Mine"

However, if our dictionary contains this list of properties and values:

```
Snack = "Caviar"
Genre = "Comedy" 
Movie = ""
```

This would execute `Rule 4` and the Movie value would get set to "Big"

After reading all the discussions and blogs on WF rules, I am unable to see if it is even possible to process rules without a concrete object. If WF is unable to do this, does anyone know of a rules engine that can?

I have looked at WebRule also which cannot do this for the same reasons.

Comment: FYI rules from WF3 are deprecated now, as is that version of the framework.

Comment: Are you saying .Net 4.5 does not have workflow rules?

Comment: Yep.  You can still use them, but they are deprecated.  WF4 dispenses with them altogether.

Comment: Sorry, but the information from @Will is incorrect. The WF3 rules types are **NOT** deprecated in .NET 4.5, though many other WF3 types are deprecated. Supporting evidence: [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.rules(v=vs.110).aspx) and [official blog posting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflowteam/archive/2012/02/08/deprecatingwf3.aspx)

Comment: @kreinsch: Nice blog article.  It appears from that source that you are correct.  However, it seems odd as the article states that you can use rules with WF4, but 4 does not use rules.  So, in effect, it's like saying you can still use generic collections (or any other specific part of the framework) with 4 :/  I guess rules are going to still be around.  Until a new framework update shows up with `[Obsolete]` all over rules...

Comment: What do you mean by "process rules without a concrete object"?

Every rule needs some way to access the your data.

Have you tried implementing with something simple like the Dictionary you described?

Comment: Yes Dictionary is what I need to use, where the keys are not known until runtime. Is this possible?